# Genitives like "axeos"

Tags: greek, morphology, declension, noun, third-declension

I recently encountered a text written in Latin in Finland about two centuries ago using the form *axeos*.
From context it was clear that it was a genitive, and it looks just like the Greek genitive of words like *polis*.
But the word *axis* has also a Latin style genitive *axis*, and L&S mentions it as the only genitive.

When do genitives like *axeos* appear in Latin?
I assume they only appear in (perceived) Greek loans where nominative and genitive would look alike, ending in *-is*.
Is this form restricted to some contexts, eras, words, or authors?
Is only used when ambiguity between nominative and genitive would be an issue?
I understand the form but, frankly, I have no idea when to expect it.
Any insight is welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For what it's worth, I think this was simply a mistake.

Greek nouns ending in *-is* are generally third-declension *i*-stems, like *póli-s*. In Attic, these nouns tend to show an *-i-* in some forms and an *-ei-* in others, with no particular logic that I've ever learned; quantitative metathesis and contraction then make the forms even less predictable. The genitive singular of *póli-s*, for example, shifted from **póli-os* to **poléi-os* to *póle-ōs*.

Since these forms are so unpredictable, they have to be memorized rather than derived; I imagine Greek-speakers just learned that *-is* went to *-eōs* in the genitive, as a special rule, treating *pól-* as the stem and *-eōs* as the ending.

This writer seems to have then brought it into Latin as a sort of hypercorrection: *axis* is a native Latin word that never came through Greek (the Greek cognate is *áxōn*, with a regular genitive *áxon-os*), and Latin never had the vowel alternations and shifts that created *póleōs*.

Comment: You have convinced me that it is most likely hypercorrection. Now I just wonder how common it is.

Comment: Compare in English the clever people who say “rhinoceri” instead of “rhinoceroses”, not knowing that the true plural would be “rhinocerotes”.